# Spread two Seqs scala

Tags: scala

I have a function like so:

```scala
def myFunc(name: String, args: String*): String = {
    (Seq("(", name) ++ args.map(_.toString) ++ Seq(")")).mkString
}
```

which works.

I was just wondering if there was something similar to ES6 spread,
so I could do

```scala
Seq("(", name, ...args, ")").mkString
```

I saw `: _*` operator but it looks its only for last argument so wouldn't work here.

Anything similar in Scala?

Comment: No, but you may have just `args.mkString(s"(${name}", "", ")")`

Comment: Ah yeah Thanks, thats pretty nice